# What to do with a list of verbs with different prepositional needs?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

For example:
The community was not supportive of, or happy with the result.
The community was not supportive or happy with the result.

So when using two sets of verbs and prepositions (listing) in a sentence, do you need to state both prepositions? 
I think yes.  If the preposition is the same, then no.
Am I correct?

Comment: Preliminary comment: Do not bunch them, never. Each verb-prep. combo should stay tied. "Neither was the community **supportive of** nor **happy with** the result," to slightly rephrase it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, verbs needing different prepositions need each to keep their own: your two example sentences actually mean different things.

> The community was not supportive of, or happy with, the result.
>   The community was not supportive or happy with the result.

The first means that the community did not support the result; the second says it wasn't happy with the result and didn't support something else, because *supportive* doesn't go with *with* and therefore it doesn't go with *with the result*. There could [and probably normally would] be a comma after *supportive* but it doesn't necessarily need it.

Incidentally you might consider using *Neither...nor* where there are two negatives: "The community was neither supportive of, nor happy with, the result."

You **can** get away with not repeating the preposition when it's the same for both verbs. Note the second comma in the examples below though: omitting that will separate *built* from the *care*. If you want to make this sort of sentence negative, *neither...nor* is required.

> The Town Hall was built, and the decoration applied, with considerable care.
>   The Town Hall was neither built, nor the decoration applied, with any care at all.